# Failed to populate docusign api custom field

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to populate custom field ('mobile' in this example) by using Docusign PHP api client. Here is the code piece I am using:

```
// Get template role
  $templateRole = $docusignClient->templateRole([
    'name' => $client1->getFullName(),
    'email' => $client1->email,
    'role_name' => json_decode($template->docusign_template)->recipient[0]->role,
    'tabs' => array('textTabs'=>array(
      array('tabLabel'=>'first name','value'=>$client1->first_name),
      array('tabLabel'=>'last name','value'=>$client1->last_name),
      array('tabLabel'=>'mobile','value'=>$client1->mobile),
      array('tabLabel'=>'email','value'=>$client1->email),
      ))
  ]);
```

Here is my standard fields and custom field defination in the template:

[template fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ADen.png)

The standard fields like `first name`, `last name` & `email` populated properly, however, the custom field `mobile` failed. Only a blank area displayed like below:

[custom field failed to populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEW0r.png)

I have searched similar questions and have not seen any solution. Did I missed anything? How can I get this up and running? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The custom field name needs to match with the one on the picture.
Change it to "Mobile", as in the picture in this post.